# Cannot compile styles.xml after upgrading Xamarin to latest version

Tags: android, xamarin

Lately I upgraded Xamarin to latest version and my project stopped compiling. The errors are:

```
Styles.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'.
Styles.xml(2): error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'.
Styles.xml(2): error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimary'.
Styles.xml(2): error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorPrimaryDark'.
Styles.xml(2): error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'drawerArrowStyle'.
```

The fragment of XML which is pointed to by the error looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/MyDrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
```

What can be the cause? How can I fix it?

Comment: That fragment looks fine, think there is something else wrong.

Comment: If you are using xamarin forms, make sure you extend from FormsAppCompatActivity

Comment: I use Xamarin.Android, but it seems more like problem with libraries or resources than with (im)proper inheritance... or am I wrong?

Comment: can you run the project? looks like an error woth xamarin. I sometimes get it but if I ignore it , it still runs.

Comment: Missing android Sdk or incorrect version for some of xamarin android nuget packages/components?

Comment: If using `android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` doesn't work, you should really check the rest of your xml. The problem might be elsewhere. If that also doesn't work, Select Properties on your android project and set the "Compile using Android Version" to explicitly instead of using the latest platform